# Prevent usage of base Form/Control class

Tags: c#

I am working on a project where we have 10's of Forms and Controls.
As the program was being written, a inherited Form and Control was made that was supposed to be used for all future forms/controls, so if there is ever a change that needs to be made on the control level. It would be applied across the whole application.

This is being followed most of the time, but every so often, a form or control is made using the base class.

Is there a way to prevent the usage of the basic Form/Control and force the usage of inherited Form/Control  apart from the specific whitelist?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019

Comment: Can these be forced on all developers? Last time I used Roslyn analyzer, it was only for myself

Comment: You should run all code analysis on your continuous integration server.

Comment: They're included in your project and applied at compile time, so all developers will see the hints or warnings.

Comment: @JonasH sadly we do not have that yet, we are planning on it in the near future though.

Comment: @CodeCaster so to understand, I am currently looking at that and it doesn't seem I cant make new rules apart from making my own analyzer? Nevermind, it seems you can make your own Code qualty/style rule

Comment: If you do not have a CI system the question is kind of moot. You need to define a official build environment, without that there are a whole bunch of issues that may be introduced without anyone noticing.

Comment: Yeah, we had issues like that before, where different version of libraries were shipped with the product, which caused  issues on certain computers because they didn't have the backwards compatibility.

Comment: I found a solution that works in our current development flow and posted it as an answer, but I have added your comments as the 1st solution to the problem, because that is a better way to do it than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the options provided to me in the original question comments, I came to my own solution that will work for our development and deployment flow.

**1st solution provided by @CodeCaster and @JonasH that you should use**

- User @CodeCaster [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256631/prevent-usage-of-base-form-control-class?noredirect=1#comment117138420_66256631) that I look into .Net Code Quality
  and Styles that is offered by the Roselyn analyzer.
- User @JonasH suggested that I look into deploying a Continuous integration server, which would be used for building our software.

While this solution is something that should be implemented, that is not currently possible in our current development flow.

**2nd solution**

C# allows you to use Reflection to iterate through all classes and find any classes who's base type is of a type Form

```
        Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Type[] myTypes = myAssembly.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in myTypes)
        {
            if (type?.BaseType?.Name == "Form")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
            }
        }
```

You can then use that to filter out the "whitelisted" Forms which are supposed to be inheriting from Form and notify the developer of any other Forms that are not whitelisted